# Retrieve Result from comparing multiple colums in a single table

Tags: sql

```
FID RP  Area    Count
1   100 0.780   1
2   100 0.906   2
2   500 0.094   2
3   100 1.000   1
4   100 1.000   1
5   100 0.784   2
5   500 0.916   2
6   100 0.332   3
6   500 0.780   3
6   555 0.643   3
```

In the above table, i want to retrieve the columns where Area>0.4. This will retrieve 8 rows. But i want answer in other way.
Look at Case where `FID =5`. In this, the area of RP 100 and 500 satisfy the criteria, but the output should be given high weigtage for `RP =100`. For the case where `FID =6`, `RP=100` did not satisfy the criteria, but `RP=500` and `RP=555` satisfies the criteria. I want the weigtage to be given to `RP=500`.

Required Result:

```
FID RP  Area    Count
1   100 0.78007 1
2   100 0.90626 2
3   100 1   1
4   100 1   1
5   100 0.7835  2
6   500 0.78    3
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

So, you want the first row for each id where the value of `Area` exceeds 0.4 and "first" is ordered by `RP`.

Window function provide the mechanism to do this.  Most databases support `row_number()`:

```
select FID, RP, Area, "Count"
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by fid order by rp) as seqnum
      from t
      where Area > 0.4
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The subquery filters the rows so only rows with valid values of `Area` are included.  The `row_number()` function assigns sequential values to the rows within an `fid` (because of the `partition by` clause).  The values are assigned in order by `rp` (due to the `order by` clause).